# Unable to compile a simple ODBC++ test program: undefined reference

Tags: compiler-errors, g++, unixodbc

I am attempting to build a very simple `libodbc++` program. Lately, we have noticed a strange memory leak, which we believe originates somewhere in between ODBC++ and IDS driver - I am writing a test which aims to prove that.

I compile the test with using the following command:

```
g++ -m32 -fPIC -Wall -g \
    -I<PATH_TO_LIB_REPO>/odbc++/0_2_3/include \
    -I<PATH_TO_LIB_REPO>/IBM/IDS/CSDK/lnx/4.10.UC9W1post/CSDK/incl/cli \
    -I<PATH_TO_LIB_REPO>/IBM/IDS/CSDK/lnx/4.10.UC9W1post/CSDK/incl/esql \
    -L/LIBS \
    -l"odbc++-mt" \
    demo.cpp
```

And the `demo.cpp` is rather trivial:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <odbc++/drivermanager.h>
#include <odbc++/connection.h>
// ... other includes go here

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    string dsn = "DSN=mydb;;uid=username;RECVTIMEOUT=900;pwd=password";

    odbc::Connection* conn = odbc::DriverManager::getConnection(dsn.c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

But, I keep getting:

```
/tmp/cc8MhaKk.o: In function `main':
demo.cpp:34: undefined reference to `odbc::DriverManager::getConnection(std::string const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please ignore the line number (34) as my example above is stripped down of some extra parts.

I cannot get to the bottom of it. Notice that I am linking against the libodbc++-mt - I tried listing the symbols from that .so file and, surely enough, the call to `DriverManager::getConnection` is there.

One difference that I noticed that that libodbc++ uses `ODBCXX_STRING`, which I would assume typedefs into string, but so far I haven't been able to confirm that.

Does anyone have any hint on how to resolve this?

## UPDATE:

Demangled symbols from `libodbc++-mt.so`:

```
libodbc++-mt.so:00016c60 T _ZN4odbc13DriverManager13getConnectionERKN8stlp_std12basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEE
odbc::DriverManager::getConnection(stlp_std::basic_string<char, stlp_std::char_traits<char>, stlp_std::allocator<char> > const&)

libodbc++-mt.so:00016cd0 T _ZN4odbc13DriverManager13getConnectionERKN8stlp_std12basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEES9_S9_
odbc::DriverManager::getConnection(stlp_std::basic_string<char, stlp_std::char_traits<char>, stlp_std::allocator<char> > const&, stlp_std::basic_string<char, stlp_std::char_traits<char>, stlp_std::allocator<char> > const&, stlp_std::basic_string<char, stlp_std::char_traits<char>, stlp_std::allocator<char> > const&)
```

Comment: "I tried listing the symbols from that .so file and, surely enough, the call to DriverManager::getConnection is there."
 Look again. Is there a symbol that demangles *exactly* as
 `odbc::DriverManager::getConnection(std::string const&)`?

Comment: Very good point there. I have known that our app uses `STLPort`, but after demangling the symbols, I was kinda surprised to find that our flavor of `libodbc++-mt` uses `stlp_std::basic_string` instead of `std::string`...

Comment: Regardless of my test, I can confirm that our app uses `std::string` and not the STLPort string. What is currently unclear to me is which build process makes subtle transformation from `std::string` to `stlp_std::basic_string`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With key hint from Mike Kinghan, I was able to get the test compiled.

First, I've uncovered that my `libodbc++` did not use `std::string` but instead `stlp_std::string` (which belongs to `STLPort`).

Second, linked the `libstlport.so` against my test program, after which, it started showing other compiler error which were easily overcome.

Finally, after adjusting the code, I was able to compile and run the test.

**The bad new:** I have not able to observe memory leak which I hoped to see :)